# overflow the contents of one div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs on a page and the first div has text content only.

Currently, when the content of the first div overflows it gets truncated since the CSS for the first div is:

```
.one {
  overflow: hidden
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But on an overflow, could I make the overflow text appear in a 2nd div?

For example, let's say the text content in the first div is "Hello there" and it displays "Hello" but "there" is cut off because of overflow hidden, can I make "there" appear in a 2nd div?

I'm sure this is not out the box behaviour but I wondered if its possible or if anyone knows a lib to do this. Thanks.

Comment: This is possible, but you'd need to take the `div` elements out of normal document flow using `float` or `position: absolute` so that they can overlap. It would help to see your HTML.

Comment: it's a bit strange as a need ... can you give a clear use case for this?

Comment: think of an article, the first few words are styled differently (in the first div) to the rest of the article (in the second div). However, the content of the article is not split into title and content in some nicely organised JSON but is just one big blob of text.

Comment: What you describe sounds like [CSS Regions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-regions-1/). Browser support is poor: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions

Comment: @Turnip please add an answer, that's great to know and worth a +1

Comment: I don't think it's worth an answer since support has been dropped by all browsers except IE. Making it completely unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native capacities of CSS do not allow for this kind of behaviour, since it is quite special.

If you want to manipulate the text so that it gets displayed in different parts of your DOM, depending on a determinate critera, you will have to use Javascript to do so.

Use Javascript to create a kind of parser that detects if the text matches the criteria needed to separate them, and if it does so, manipulate the content so that it is displayed in the correct  element.

**EDIT:**

If what you are trying to do, though, is basically format differently the first line from the rest of the text, what you might need is simple the [::fist-line pseudoselector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp).

This way you can set the first line to have a determinate size, color, etc.Notice though that only [a certain amount of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line#Allowable_properties) can be applied to this selector.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem tonight. I have 2 divs side by side, I want the text of the first div to spill over into the 2nd div if needed.  I solved it with z-index, make the div with the text that spills out have a higher z-index than the adjacent one that you want to spill over.

Comment: an example would have been helpfull